# "A registration already exists for URI" when hosting same service for HTTPS and HTTP

Tags: wcf, http, iis, binding, https

I am trying to host the same service inside the same website using two endpoints one HTTP and the other HTTPS.

**The problem is I can happily call one service (whichever I call first works) but then call to the other fails until I iisreset and try again. SO I can happily call both but one at a time until a process recycle.**

I have exhausted (or I think I have) all relevant Q&A and documents that I could find and none of them seem to help me. The level of documentation of MSDN regarding these cases (which should be faily common) is appalling and nothing works as it seems.

I have used Host/BaseAddresses/BaseAddress with no luck and whenever I used it, I get another error (cannot find an HTTPS scheme).

I have folder called Secure which is enabled for HTTPS inside IIS.

I have disabled mex so no metadata allowed which I got passed previous errors.

Anyone got a clue? I am cluless...

```
  <service name="Namespace.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehaviour">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
      </baseAddresses> 
    </host> 
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/Services/MyService.svc/MyService"
              name="MyService"   binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="myWsHttpBinding" contract="Namespace.IMyService" />

    <endpoint address="https://localhost/Services/Secure/MySslService.svc/MySslService"
              name="MySslService"   binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="MySslServiceBinding" contract="Namespace.IMyService" />
  </service>
```

.....

```
   <behavior name="MyBehaviour">
      <custom1/>
      <custom2/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles" roleProviderName="CustomProvider"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="Some" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />

        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="SomeClass, SomeDll"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
```

Original error is:

> A registration already exists for URI
>   'http://localhost/Services/....'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: A
>   registration already exists for URI
>   'http://localhost/Services/....'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: A
>   registration already exists for URI
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.UriPrefixTable`1.RegisterUri(Uri
>   uri, HostNameComparisonMode
>   hostNameComparisonMode, TItem item)
>   +320    System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportManager.Register(TransportChannelListener
>   channelListener) +380
>
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener
>   channelListener) +816
>
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback
>   selectTransportManagerCallback) +121
>
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +125
>
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +789
>
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.DatagramChannelDemuxer`2.OnOuterListenerOpen(ChannelDemuxerFilter
>   filter, IChannelListener listener,
>   TimeSpan timeout) +606
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelListener`3.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +91
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +789
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +375

Here is the WCF Trace log error:

> The ChannelDispatcher at
>   'http://localhost/Services/...' with
>   contract(s) '"IMyService"' is unable
>   to open its IChannelListener.
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String
>   relativeVirtualPath)
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object
>   state)
>   System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object
>   state)
>   System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes,
>   NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>   System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32
>   error, UInt32 bytesRead,
>   NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes,
>   NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I fixed my problem. The issue was I was under impression that I had to create a secure folder in IIS and put the .svc file in there to guarantee SSL transmission. It turned out that it is not the case and all I had to do was to use the same .svc file and just define 2 endpoints:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost/Services/MyService.svc/MyService"
          name="MyService"   binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="myWsHttpBinding" contract="Namespace.IMyService" />

<endpoint address="https://localhost/Services/MyService.svc/MySecureService"
          name="MySslService"   binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="MySslServiceBinding" contract="Namespace.IMyService" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible the nested directories are confusing IIS - I have had this happen before although not in the WCF context.  Try changing the endpoint addresses to:

```
address="http://localhost/MyService"
address="https://localhost/MySslService"
```

Can you try hosting the application from a console app instead of IIS?  I'm pretty certain IIS is causing your problem somehow but this might confirm it.

If it's possible, I'd also try to isolate the problem by removing some of the configuration detail - eg bindingConfiguration and behaviorConfiguration.

Obviously these are just debugging steps I'd perform (you may have already) to try and isolate the problem - sorry I haven't got a full answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go with non-nested structure tomorrow although it is a bit complicated with the way these are defined and I have to secure one folder - but is possible.

Comment: It might work out simpler to test the nested folder concept with a dummy service on a VM - start with something that works and see if you can break it :)

Comment: No luck as I thought. It falls apart in WCF not in IIS. I in fact even found in the MS code where it fails using Reflector but cannot figure out exactly how to get passed it.

Comment: Bugger. The configuration you have posted is far from vanilla - could you post the simplest configuration you have tried? That should rule some things out.  I have tested your general scenario recently and had no problems.  The differences were that I hosted in a console instead of IIS, used wsHttpBinding only, didn't use custom behaviors (authentication defaults to Windows), used simpler endpoint addresses, and used custom ports instead of defaults. Also Client and Server were different VMs.

Comment: If you think there's a bug in WCF you might be able to report it at http://wcf.codeplex.com/